# How to insert vector image using the Google Slides API?

Tags: google-slides-api

My goal is to insert a vector drawing using a Google Slide extension. My files are in SVG, but we can assume that I am able to convert them in any vector format that would be required.

Using either the standard or advanced Slides API, it seems that I need to insert a [`Shape`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#shape). When I look at the shape [types](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#Page.Type), I see a `CUSTOM` option. However, I do not know how to pass the data for this custom shape (what is the expected data structure and where to pass it)

Ideally, I would like to insert a vector drawing by importing one of the supported vector drawing file types, like `emf`.

Comment: You can try (not tested this solution) to import your vector image to Google Drawings, then insert in to Slides

Comment: I want to do this from the API (no manual step)

Comment: any progress/ideas with this? I did not find a way to load SVG into Google Drawings either.